# In what respect vs How

Tags: sentence-construction

When making questions, is there any remarkable difference between **in what respect** and **how**? I'm asking for cases or contexts where only one of them can be used.

Comment: You need to provide further context and clarification because there are some situations where "in what respect" can replace "how" (e.g., "In what respect do you mean?" and "How do you mean?"), but in others, it can't (e.g., "In what respect are you?" and "How are you?").

Comment: @BenjaminHarman You've pointed my question in the direction I want... *in what situations "in what respect" can't replace "how"?*

Comment: If you're asking for a collectively exhaustive list of every single contextual situation in which it can't, your question is going to get deleted for being too broad, if for no other reason than such a list would exceed the space allowed for any answer. You can't reasonably expect people to sit and dream up every single possible situation where "how" may be used where "in what respect" may not.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Oh, I got the point. I want just some relevant cases that come to mind...